# Bundles not working in my ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundles

I wrote this code:

BundleConfig.cs

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/js/jquery-{version}.min.js")); // bundle jQuery

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapcss").Include(
            "~/css/bootstrap.min.css"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include(
           "~/js/bootstrap.min.js")); // bundle jquery

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
            "~/css/MYStyle.min.css"
            , "~/css/font-awesome.min.css"
            , "~/css/JF-flat.min.css"));
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }

 <% Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapcss");%>
 <% Styles.Render("~/bundles/css");%> <% Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery"); %> 
<% Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery"); %>
```

and these settings in the `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="BundleModule"/>
        <add name="BundleModule" 
             type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Even I change `Debug=false`.

I added this code also in `Global.asax.cs` :

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) { // // Code that runs on application startup // // Application["visitor"] = 0; BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles); }
```

I want fix this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: You have a typo in `new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqurey")`

Comment: No this for script which I did not mention here

Comment: What _does_ render? What if you put something else in SiteMaster.aspx, does that render? Why is it named like that, shouldn't it be Site.master?

Comment: It is not render any CSS

Comment: If I put link working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution thank God.

The solution is just this:

```
<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapcss")%>
<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/css") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs") %>
```

Comment: Namely what the issue was for me was 

<% Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapcss"); %>

had to add the ":" after the first percentage and removing the semicolon after

<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapcss") %>

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to render some style / script bundles?

```
<% Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
```

Comment: No I write it all

Comment: <% Styles.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapcss");%>
     <% Styles.Render("~/bundles/css");%>
     <% Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqurey"); %>
     <% Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqurey"); %>

Comment: Use show source command in browser. Check if they are included in HTML

Comment: I added this code also in Global.asax.cs :void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //    // Code that runs on application startup
        //  //  Application["visitor"] = 0;
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        }